# Login process when using external auth (facebook) with web api 2

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm a little confused on the process of authenticating with Facebook through web api after the user has externally registered with the service. With local accounts, you just call the `/Token` method with your user credentials, but the external auth flow seems a bit obscure.

I have a standard Web API 2 project with single user authentication set up. Using Fiddler I can register a user and access API methods that have the `[Authorize]` data annotation added.

What is the process for handling authentication through Facebook after the user has previously registered? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you checked out the `Facebood SDK` I am sure this would be a viable place to start in regards to examples and documentation do a google seacrh on this `C# handling authentication through Facebook`

Comment: Yes, and the page that I think might have that information is showing a 'Page not found' error. Other than that, it looks like there is nothing specific in the documentation.